# How do I get Chef to find an Active Directory User?

Tags: active-directory, centos, chef-infra

Error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::UserIDNotFound
--------------------------------
cannot determine user id for 'builduser', does the user exist on this system?
```

Here is my (trimmed) chef recipe:

```rb
if node['platform'] == 'centos'
  package 'yum-utils'
  execute 'yum-config-manager --enable cr'
end

include_recipe "python::source"

...

## Setup key for jenkins... https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ssh_authorized_keys
ssh_authorize_key 'builduser@supermarket.com' do
    key 'AAAAB3Nz...hiOQ=='
    user 'builduser'
    group 'builduser'
end
```

This user is *not* created by this recipe, but already exists in the Active Directory that this CentOS VM is connected to.

Anyone knows how to tell chef to go read this from Active Directory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You might be running in to the dreaded "nsswitch.conf reload" issue. Does it work the second time or does it always fail? If it works the second time, it might be because `/etc/nsswitch.conf` was only updated earlier in that Chef run, and those changes won't be visible until the Chef process restarts due to how libc caches the nsswitch database config. If it always fails, check that the machine does have the correct nsswitch config to make AD users visible. Linking to AD on PAM alone wouldn't be enough for the user entries to work.

Comment: It didn't fail the second time, but didn't succeed either. Two issues: (1) It created /home/builduser rather than the HOME configured in AD (/home/orgz_test/builduser). (2) Everything it touched is owned by root!

I think this is an issue with the ssh_authorize_key recipe. I have filed a issue with them.

Comment: That definition seems to have some funky fallback code that assumes /home, check if Chef prints any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround / solution was to create file resources owned by root, and then chown them to the user. Somehow... chown doesn't seem to have a problem with AD.

```
file '/home/orgz_test/builduser/.ssh/authorized_keys' do
  content 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz...hiOQ== builduser@supermarket.com'
  mode '0644'
end

# user and group setting in 'file' or 'directory' does not work... so, do it manually
bash "Change ownership" do
    user "root"
    group "root"
    code <<-EOC
        chown builduser /home/orgz_test/builduser/.ssh/authorized_keys
        chgrp builduser_g /home/orgz_test/builduser/.ssh/authorized_keys
        chmod 600 /home/hedgeservtest.com/cashmgmt/.ssh/authorized_keys
    EOC
end
```

Not the prettiest solution.. but works.

Comment: chown works because it creates a new process that uses the new nsswitch settings

Answer (score 0):

1. redirect user keys to a different area;  /etc/ssh/keys/ for instance:

```
--- /etc/ssh/sshd_config
+++ /etc/ssh/sshd_config
@@ -41,1 +41,1 @@
-AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
+AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/keys/keys-%u
```

coding like

```
# bad pseudocoding; at own risk!
include_attribute 'openssh::default'
default['openssh']['server']['authorized_keys_file'] += ' /etc/ssh/keys/keys-%u'
```

2. chown them root.root and 400 since only sshd needs to read them
3. manage them by chef anyway

```
# bad pseudocoding; at own risk!
directory /etc/ssh/keys
keys.each do |user,strarrkeys|

  file "/etc/ssh/keys/keys-#{user}" do  # make this DRYer for added credit
    content strarrkeys.join("\n")
    user  'root'
    group 'root'
    mode  '400'  #600?
    action strarrkeys.empty? ? :delete : :create
  end
end
```

4. miller time